# Updating a previous value in the database with the value that was saved before it( Real Time Database Firebase)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm trying to update a table with a value that was already saved there before, for example a counter that receives the same number that was saved before it, only to make changes and save it in the table again and activate the trigger for me.

```
              getCounterSpeaking().then((counterSpeaking) => {
                         this will activate the trigger
                      counterSpeakingUpdating(counterSpeaking +1)
                       but I want that this will activate to.
                      counterSpeakingUpdating(counterSpeaking)

                  });
                  
              })`
```

[image]

the get function:

```
    const getCounterSpeaking = async () => {
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
  const reference= get(child(dbRef, `counter-speaking`))
  const snapshot= await reference
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const data = snapshot.val()
            const dataFromDatabase = Object.values(data);

            //console.log("getCounterSpeaking",dataFromDatabase[0])
            return dataFromDatabase[0]
        }
        
}
```

the update function:

```
const counterSpeakingUpdating = (newCounter) => {
    const db = getDatabase()
    set(ref(db, 'counter-speaking'), {
        counter: newCounter
    });
}
```

Comment: So you want to perform an action whenever "counter-speaking" changes either locally or in the database?

Comment: I have an OnChange function that listens to the changes I make locally, the problem is that when I enter the same value that was before the value is not updated in the database and the Onchange function is not activated for me.

Comment: So `counterSpeakingUpdating` is the `setState` callback from a call to `useState`?

Comment: It updates the table in firebase and after the value is updated, it activates a trigger that also updates the state.

Comment: Please provide the full source/declarations of `counterSpeakingUpdating` and `getCounterSpeaking`.

Comment: I added these simple firebase functions.